# Can I use #14 wire on a 20A circuit for a compressor outlet?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

Installing a single receptacle, non gfi, on a 20 amp breaker to be used only for a specific piece of equipment (compressor). Compressor specs say, “power consumption will average between 9-11 amps of power and spike near 16 amps”. Can I get away with 14 gage wire? This is for a home food Freeze dryer[image]

Comment: Are we talking an air compressor here, or some sort of refrigeration device? Can you post a photo of the appliance's nameplate if there is an appliance nameplate present, or of the motor's nameplate if there there is no appliance nameplate to be had?

Comment: Also, why are you framing it as "Can I get away with...?" Is the concern having to run out and get materials, or...?

Comment: The breaker is not there to protect your appliance, it's the to protect the wiring.

Comment: Added a pic.  I have the 14 gage just don’t want go get 12. Time and money

Comment: It’s actually a vacuumed pump

Comment: 20 amp breaker? 12 gauge wire, period. There is nothing else to discuss. You might be aware of this funky idea to not overload a 14 awg wire on your 20 amp circuit but the next owner of the house certainly won't. If you want 14 gauge wire then downgrade the breaker to 15 amps. Don't funk with electricity like that. You've probably wasted more time rationalizing this terrible idea and asking this question than it would have taken to install the proper wiring.

Answer (score 3):

20A breaker, 12Ga wire. Nothing special about it. The breaker protects the wire, the NEC specifically limits 10, 12 and 14 Ga wire to 30, 20 and 15 Amps respectively.

*"Get away with" means you know it's wrong, so, go with what you know, and don't try to "get away with" something wrong, especially something so trivially inexpensive to do right.*

Answer (score 3):

### You'll need the 12AWG wire, even under Article 430 rules

For a single motor and nothing else, we start with NEC 430.6(A)(1) to find the motor full load current; this sends us to NEC Table 430.248, which gives us 13.8A for a ¾HP, 115VAC motor like yours.  We then need to look at NEC 430.22, which requires us to multiply that by 125% for a non-duty-cycle rated application, and gives us a minimum circuit ampacity of 17.25A, which exceeds the 15A hard limit on what 14AWG NM can handle.  So, you'll have to use the 12AWG, basically no matter how you slice or dice it.

Answer (score 2):

Use 12 AWG.
Reason: Later, you or someone else will come across the outlet and think, "Oh Wow! a 20 Amp outlet! and will either plug a lot of stuff into it, or will want to expand the power and add more outlets.
If you spent the extra couple dollars to use the 12 AWG now, you won't have to re do it later! You don't need to be heating the insulation in your walls anyway. (Also I'm pretty sure wire thinner than 12 AWG is not to code for 20A circuits.)

Comment: Good thought, however It’s temporary. Moving next fall and will take the breaker and with me. Just doing this in the garage.

Comment: If the power spike is greater than your rated cable, that could be a problem. I would say, to be safe, go with 12. I dont think your house will blow up if you just use the 14. We all do "good enough" stuff every now and again. However, there is a zero chance of exceeding  the rating of your wire if you just use 12.

Answer (score 0):

NEC 240.4(D) prohibits #14 on a 20A breaker for a receptacle.

If it comes with a standard 15A (NEMA5-15) plug you can run it on 15A breaker and #14 awg receptacle. If you expect to share the circuit with other loads the Use #12 and a 20A.

A 15A breaker doesn't trip right at 15A, it is designed to handle temporary overcurrents. Low overcurrents trip slow, high overcurrents trip fast. Depending on the exact model breaker when you look at an inverse time curve for breakers you will see 107% will likely never trip. Some breakers might be more sensitive than NEMA standards, but not significantly.

[image]